# Wont display my database info in my java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

i have this code and it wont display the stuff i have in my database. I created a table and inserted some data. I know all that is good and working. But the problem i have is it wont display any of the of the data and i have no idea why...so if someone could help me out that would be great. Just dont undertand what i did wrong or if im missing something here is my code. Im using tomcat if that matters for the servlet part.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class test extends HttpServlet{

 static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/csc3610_Connection";

 //  Database credentials
  static final String USER = "root";
  static final String PASS = "";


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{


  // Set response content type
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  String title = "Database Result";
  String docType =
    "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
     "transitional//en\">\n";
     out.println(docType +
     "<html>\n" +
     "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
     "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
     "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n");

     Connection conn=null;
     Statement stmt=null;
  try{
     // Register JDBC driver
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     // Open a connection
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

     // Execute SQL query
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     String sql;
     sql = "SELECT FROM csc3610_Connection.Employees";
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

     // Extract data from result set
     while(rs.next()){
        //Retrieve by column name
        int id  = rs.getInt("id");
        int age = rs.getInt("age");
        String first = rs.getString("first");
        String last = rs.getString("last");

        //Display values
        out.println("ID: " + id + "<br>");
        out.println(", Age: " + age + "<br>");
        out.println(", First: " + first + "<br>");
        out.println(", Last: " + last + "<br>");
     }
     out.println("</body></html>");

     // Clean-up environment
     rs.close();
     stmt.close();
     conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
     //Handle errors for JDBC
     se.printStackTrace();
  }catch(Exception e){
     //Handle errors for Class.forName
     e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
     //finally block used to close resources
     try{
        if(stmt!=null)
           stmt.close();
     }catch(SQLException se2){
     }// nothing we can do
     try{
        if(conn!=null)
        conn.close();
     }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
     }//end finally try
  } //end try
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the SELECT statement is wrong. You have to use

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM csc3610_Connection.Employees";
```

Then please refactor the piece of code which retrieves the database connection. You shouldn't open a new connection on every request. Furthermore a class name in Java should start with a capital letter. Take a look at the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

For example:

```
private Connection connection = null;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    super.init(config);
    try 
    {
        // Load the MySQL driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        DB_URL, "root", "");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    { 
        throw new UnavailableException(this, "Couldn't load database driver");
    }    
    catch (SQLException e) 
    { 
        throw new UnavailableException(this, "Couldn't get db connection");
    }    
}
```

and then in your doGet-Method use something like this:

```
     // Execute SQL query
     stmt = connection.createStatement();
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM csc3610_Connection.Employees";
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: ok i fixed the "SELECT * FROM csc3610_Connection.Employees"; part but it looks like its not connecting to my database because i put in a out.println("got connection") and thats not showing up so im thinking its not connecting to my database..do you have any idea y?

Comment: Are you sure, that you've deployed a mysql-connector in Tomcat? If not then download and extract the JAR file, and copy it to "$CATALINA_HOME/lib". This will make the driver available to JDBC.

Comment: i did not do that let me try it

Comment: And don't forget to restart Tomcat